# Infra Red sketch "not declared in this scope"

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

I'm pretty new at Arduino and I'm trying to upload a sketch with IR sensor to control LED-s.
I copy the code from internet,download library,I put my infrared codes for TV remote where I want and it says:"not declared in this scope"

Code and error:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

const int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
const int redPin = 6;
const int greenPin = 9;


void setup(){
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
    if (irrecv.decode(&results)){

        switch(results.value){
          case E0E036C9: //Keypad button "5"
          digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);
          delay(2000);
          digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
          }

        switch(results.value){
          case E0E028D7: //Keypad button "2"
          digitalWrite(greenPin, HIGH);
          delay(2000);
          digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);
          }

        irrecv.resume(); 
    }
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Kandzija\Desktop\saneta\saneta.ino: In function 'void loop()':
saneta:21: error: 'E0E036C9' was not declared in this scope
           case E0E036C9: //Keypad button "5"
                ^
saneta:28: error: 'E0E028D7' was not declared in this scope
           case E0E028D7: //Keypad button "2"
                ^
exit status 1
'E0E036C9' was not declared in this scope
```

Can you help me guys pls? 
Thank You!

Comment: E0E036C0 ... What does suppose to means those values? constants? enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numeric values in HEX need to be prefixed with `0x`:

```
case 0xE0E036C9: //Keypad button "5"
```

and

```
case 0xE0E028D7: //Keypad button "2"
```